# YouTube iFrame API duplicate requests in network tab for every new YT.Player created on the page

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have the `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` script declared one time on my page, but when I use it to create videos with these functions:

```
// "youtubeAPI" is just an object I defined to namespace all my helper functions

youtubeAPI.init = function() {
  $(".js-project-card-video").each(function() {
    youtubeAPI.createVideo($(this).attr("data-project-id"), $(this).attr("data-video-id"));
  });
};

youtubeAPI.createVideo = function(projectID, videoID) {
  var project = $(".js-project-card-video[data-project-id='" + projectID + "']");
  var identifier = "video_" + projectID;
  youtubeAPI[identifier] = project;
  youtubeAPI[identifier] = new YT.Player(youtubeAPI[identifier][0], {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    videoId: videoID,
    playerVars: {
      enablejsapi: 1,
      controls: 0,
      playsinline: 1,
      rel: 0,
      modestbranding: 1,
      showinfo: 1
    }
  });
};
```

I end up with a new, duplicate set of requests for some of the YouTube API resources, like `www-embed-player.js` and `base.js`,  in the network tab for each video. So, I see `www-embed-player.js`, `base.js`, and others listed in my network tab 5 times each.

Is this something to worry about? I would think it is cached after the first request, but still that's a lot of network requests...any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: Only what I have in the network tab. I did, however, learn that the iframes being loaded by YouTube each have their own resources inside them that get called every time an iframe loads. This is not a big deal after things get cached, but on first page load it could be a nightmare of bloat and data usage/load time.